# database query in c++

Tags: c++, database, postgresql

```
query << "SELECT DISTINCT \"internalIP\", COUNT(DISTINCT \"externalIP\"), "
    << "SUM(\"numBytes\"), SUM(\"content\") FROM \""
    << NON_DNS_TRAFFIC_SCHEMA_NAME << "\".\"" << date
    << "\" GROUP BY \"internalIP\"";
result = PQexecParams(postgreSQL, query.str().c_str(), 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
```

What does this query means? Also Any idea about function `PQexecParams()`?

Comment: Time to consult an introductory book on SQL, I think.

Comment: I believe you are using StackOverflow as some kind of programming-specific Google. This is not the case. You need to post specific questions ("any idea about function `PQexecParams()`?" is just gross, google it please).

Comment: @Andy Prowl, i googled it but it doesnt give good answers. it gives some results related to binary insertions, which i dont need to learn

Comment: I don't think that StackOverflow is a problem solver for this kind of question. You need to study a little bit, this is not a difficult problem, so, I think that you don't want to engine yourself a little bit.

Comment: I searched it but I somehow didnt see the first result in google :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find documentation on [PQexecParams at the Postgres website](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-exec.html).

The query will get the number of distinct `externalIP`s, the sum of `numbytes`, and the sum of `content` for each of the values of `internalIP`.